# how can i upgrade and fix the ubuntu i have now?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, windows-7, hp, crash

I was given an old HP Windows7 desktop.

It has NVIDIA GeForce 6150 SE graphics.

I deleted the windows partition and had installed ubuntu, then upgraded to 14.04 LTS.

In the current state, whenever I boot up and log in, the system crashes and the picture completely scrambles.

This happens at random; sometimes in the first two minutes, sometimes after a couple of hours. I would like to upgrade to the newest or best possible version without having this issue.

Comment: have you installed any Nvidia drivers?

Comment: No not that i can remember. This had to have been around two maybe three years ago

Answer (score -2):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download?_ga=1.140316400.230636145.1461620304

^^ You can easily update to the next version of Ubuntu here ^^ (the most recent is 16.04)

If you still have your previous live disc or usb depending on what you used, you can simply renew your system and drivers up to what the live disc has without losing data. (the last option is or if some functions are not working properly)

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks brotha ill definitely check it out tonight. How can i find out what it is thats making it crash? I would like to avoid transfering the same problem over to the newer system

Comment: 15.04 is the wrong version!

Comment: @TonyTone I think you have driver issues. Open additionalm drivers by searching the dash for "additional drivers" and select the latest Nvidia version avaliable. Then restart.

Comment: Forgive me Tim its 160.4

Comment: Hey jonathan thanks for that..im assuming the largest number is the newest which is nvidia 304.131... But theres 3 different. Tested, open source, and propriatary. Ima try tested first i guess. Please excuse my noobness

Comment: You can use open source but if not working immediately may need nomodeset. And to know which proprietary nVidia driver is correct for older nVidia cards: http://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html That says 304.xx is correct. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Sometimes Installs are bad which leads to misused RAM and an almost total lack of a processor, but can also lead to some issues like that with your screen. I recommend you reinstall or just install the newest edition